# python Flask and class and Object Oriented with twilio

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I am able to run twilo with Flask in python without Object oriented . In Twilo Dashboard I use webhook and set: https://123456.ngrok.io/voice
and it works fine.

However I would like to make my code Object Oriented so I can use the results of the speech recognition globally.

I tried this but when Twilo reaches my code I get this error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jul/2019 08:59:05] "POST /voice HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Here is my code why can it not find the /voice

```
app = Flask(__name__)

class MyServer(Flask):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def voice(self):
        self.resp = VoiceResponse()
        self.resp.say("What is your name?")
        print("1---------------")
        self.resp.gather(input='speech', timeout="3", action='/gather', method='POST')

        # resp.append(gather)
        print("2---------------")
        # print (str(resp))
        # resp.say("Thank you for telling us your name")
        return str(self.resp)

    @app.route("/gather", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def gather(self):
        self.resp = VoiceResponse()
        print("3---------------")
        self.speechRecogRes = request.values.get("SpeechResult", "")
        print("4--------------->" + str(self.speechRecogRes))
        self.resp.redirect('/voice')
        return str(self.resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello!!')
    app = MyServer(__name__)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I even tried changing the webhook address in Twilo Dashboard to set to self.voice:

```
https://123456.ngrok.io/self.voice
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm sorry, I'm not a Python developer and I don't have a fully formed answer for you here. I can try to guide you to the right path though.

First up, within your `MyServer` class you are using the `@app.route` decorator, but there is no `app` object to be dealing with.

As far as I can tell from looking at the Flask documentation, you can subclass Flask, but that is only to give it different behaviour at the server level.

I believe, when you want to modularise Flask applications you actually want to look into [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/). That might be your best bet if you want to follow the Flask way of doing things.

---

However, if you are sold on subclassing like this, the best example I can find of successfully using classes like this is this GitHub gist: https://gist.github.com/dplepage/2024129. It doesn't come with any comments, but hopefully it's relatively self explanatory. The idea is that you need to do the routing using `self.route` within the constructor.

So for your app, that might look a bit like this (untested):

```
class MyServer(Flask):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.route('/voice', self.voice, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        self.route('/gather', self.gather, methods=['GET', 'POST'])

    def voice(self):
        self.resp = VoiceResponse()
        self.resp.say("What is your name?")
        print("1---------------")
        self.resp.gather(input='speech', timeout="3", action='/gather', method='POST')

        # resp.append(gather)
        print("2---------------")
        # print (str(resp))
        # resp.say("Thank you for telling us your name")
        return str(self.resp)

    def gather(self):
        self.resp = VoiceResponse()
        print("3---------------")
        self.speechRecogRes = request.values.get("SpeechResult", "")
        print("4--------------->" + str(self.speechRecogRes))
        self.resp.redirect('/voice')
        return str(self.resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello!!')
    app = MyServer(__name__)
    app.run(debug=True)
```